# Finding network usage for wireless C#

Tags: c#, network-programming

I'm having this code:

```
//network 
        PerformanceCounter NetRead = null;
        PerformanceCounter NetWrite = null;
        int IntNetRec = 0;
        int IntNetSent = 0;
        foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
        {
            try
            {
                NetRead = new PerformanceCounter("Network Interface", "Bytes Received/sec", $"{nic.Description}");
                NetWrite = new PerformanceCounter("Network Interface", "Bytes Sent/sec", $"{nic.Description}");
                moocall = NetRead.NextValue(); // Remove the 0
                moocall = NetWrite.NextValue(); // Remove the 0
                Thread.Sleep(200);
                IntNetRec = IntNetRec + (int)NetRead.NextValue();
                IntNetSent = IntNetSent + (int)NetWrite.NextValue();
            }
            catch
            {

                continue;
            }
```

But i don't get my Network performance in the output/input in a table i have. It just says ZERO.

I can see that my Wireless Network Adapter is going up and down, and getting data.. But why is it not shown?

Hmm

Comment: Can you hit a breakpoint within the foreach loop?

Comment: I don't see where you pass on the values. Also, you probably shouldn't swallow exceptions silently. Especially when debugging.